# In Torch, module = nn.Padding(dim, pad, nInputDim, value, index), What does the nInputDim do?

Tags: deep-learning, torch, pytorch

Like the documentation stated 'When nInputDim is provided, inputs larger than that value will be considered batches where the actual dim to be padded will be dimension dim + 1.'
My understanding is the inputs dimensional larger than the provided nInputDim, the dimension dim will become dim + 1, but why is it ?

Comment: where did you get `nn.Padding`? can you direct us to the official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I think the doc you mentioned should be [this link](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/simple.md#nn.Padding).

Let's suppose you want to make 3 default zero padding at the end of 1(first) dim, so you will make a padding module like below:

```
require 'nn';
dim = 1
pad = 3
module = nn.Padding(dim, pad)
given_tensor = torch.ones(4, 2)
print(given_tensor)
res_tensor = module:forward(given_tensor)
print(res_tensor)
```

If you run these lines in torch interpreter, you will get result like below, you add 3 paddings at 1(first) dim successfully as you transform 4x2 tensor to 7x2 tensor.

```
 1  1
 1  1
 1  1
 1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x2]

 1  1
 1  1
 1  1
 1  1
 0  0
 0  0
 0  0
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 7x2]
```

**What happen if you specify `nInputDim` to 1 as below?**

```
require 'nn';
dim = 1
pad = 3
nInputDim = 1
module = nn.Padding(dim, pad, nInputDim)
given_tensor = torch.ones(4, 2)
print(given_tensor)
res_tensor = module:forward(given_tensor)
print(res_tensor)
```

if you run them, you will get result like below

```
 1  1
 1  1
 1  1
 1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x2]


 1  1  0  0  0
 1  1  0  0  0
 1  1  0  0  0
 1  1  0  0  0
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x5]
```

You want `nInputDim` to be 1, but your input Dim is 2, It will take first dimension, `4`, as batch size and make 3 padding to every item in the batch, it makes 4 size of 2 tensors to 4 size of 5 tensors. It works as if you make 3 padding to 2(dim = dim + 1, second) dim of tensor 4x2, which will output the same result, 4x5.